# Making a Tor pull request

Tags: source-code, git

How can I submit a pull request to the Tor [core repo](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register for a new account at the [Tor Bug Tracker](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor). If you don't want to register there is also a default account. You'll find username and password at the page.
2. Create a [new ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/newticket).
3. Depending if you have a public repository or not you can do different steps:

   - Add a link to a public repository. You can either host it on your own or use [code hosting facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities).
   - Otherwise just create a diff and append it to your ticket. Make should that the patch applies to the current master.
4. Wait until someone picks up on your ticket and sends you comments or approves your patch.

Comment: Thanks. Which method of presenting the patch would you say is easier for reviewers (public repository or diff attachment)?

Comment: I'd think best is having a public repository.